# Confusion regarding gradle multi module project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to make a multi module gradle project .I have `projectA`, `projectB` and `projectC` as my modules. `projectA` depends upon `projectB` so in my project's `build.gradle` file I added the following line

```
dependencies {
      compile project(":projectB")
}
```

I imported the project in my eclipse. In my `projectA`'s deployment assembly, `projectB` is included however its not included in build path under project tab. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you include all projects in `settings.gradle`?

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducer such that I can run it on my machine? Which Gradle version do you use?